# Implementing Haskell Logarithm function

Tags: haskell

I tried to implement logarithm algorithm, but it seems to be in a loop

```
loga_b :: Int -> Int -> Int
loga_b a b
         | b == 1    = 0
         | b == a    = 1
         | otherwise = 1 + loga_b (b `div` a) b
```

Comment: yes. Sometimes b `div` a is going to be zero. Also, there is some confusion about what's the base of the logarithm

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: First you need to clarify which of them is the base. Then you need to think what the logarithm shows. I'd define it as the number of times a can be divided by b iteratively.

Comment: You did ask the same question (or concerning the same code) yesterday and then delete it, didn't you?

Answer (score 5):

You switched the parameters in the last case - try this:

```
loga_b :: Int -> Int -> Int
loga_b a b
  | b == 1    = 0
  | b == a    = 1
  | otherwise = 1 + loga_b a (b `div` a)
```

examples:

```
λ> loga_b 2 8
3
λ> loga_b 2 17
4
```

#### remark

you don't really need the second case:

```
loga_b :: Int -> Int -> Int
loga_b a b
  | b == 1    = 0
  | otherwise = 1 + loga_b a (b `div` a)
```

if `b == a` then the last case will evaluate to the same `1`:

```
1 + loga_b a (a `div` a) 
= 1 + loga_b a 1 
= 1 + 0
= 1
```

#### making it total

as Sassa mentioned this is a partial function right now and I'm not sure how you want this fixed correctly, but I think this should do ok:

```
loga_b :: Int -> Int -> Int
loga_b a b
  | b < 0 || a < 0 = signum a * signum b * loga_b (abs a) (abs b)
  | b < a     = 0
  | b >= a     = 1 + loga_b a (b `div` a)
```

**Note** this will note give **sensible** behaviour for negative numbers *I know* - but I'm sure if the OP really needs it he can think about all the cases himself ;)

Comment: true, but I'm not sure what the definition of this should be in this case anyway (for example `log 0 = undefined` in any case (even if Haskell gives something like Infinity) - what do you propose `loga_b 3 0` should be? - Just wanted to fix the OPs obvious problem and give some hint about the unneccesary case

Comment: I'd make sure `loga_b a (b+1) >= loga_b a b`. Granted, `loga_b 3 0` can be treated as `undefined`; yet, there is no reason to treat `loga_b 3 2` like that, since `loga_b 3 1` is defined.

Comment: good point - I updated the answer and I think that should do what you proposed (but to be sure I would have take some pencil/paper and do the cases - but all ghci-test I did seemed ok to me)